# Reshape long form panel data to wide stacked time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, reshape, data-manipulation

I have panel data of the form:

```
+--------+----------+------------+----------+
|        | user_id  | order_date |  values  |
+--------+----------+------------+----------+
| 0      | 11039591 | 2017-01-01 | 3277.466 |
| 1      | 25717549 | 2017-01-01 | 587.553  |
| 2      | 13629086 | 2017-01-01 | 501.882  |
| 3      | 3022981  | 2017-01-01 | 1352.546 |
| 4      | 6084613  | 2017-01-01 | 441.151  |
| ...    | ...      | ...        | ...      |
| 186415 | 17955698 | 2020-05-01 | 146.868  |
| 186416 | 17384133 | 2020-05-01 | 191.461  |
| 186417 | 28593228 | 2020-05-01 | 207.201  |
| 186418 | 29065953 | 2020-05-01 | 430.401  |
| 186419 | 4470378  | 2020-05-01 | 87.086   |
+--------+----------+------------+----------+
```

as a Pandas DataFrame in Python.

The data is basically stacked time series data; the table contains numerous time series corresponding to observations for unique users within a certain period (2017/01 - 2020/05 above). The level of coverage for the period is likely to be very low amongst individual users, meaning that if you isolate the individual time series they're all of varying lengths.

I want to take this long-format panel data and convert it to wide format, such that each column is a day and each row corresponds to a unique user:

```
+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|          | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-03 | 2017-01-04 | 2017-01-05 |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 11039591 | 3277.466   | 6482.722   | NaN        | NaN        | NaN        |
| 25717549 | 587.553    | NaN        | NaN        | NaN        | NaN        |
| 13629086 | 501.882    | NaN        | NaN        | NaN        | NaN        |
|  3022981 | 1352.546   | NaN        | NaN        | 557.728    | NaN        |
|  6084613 | 441.151    | NaN        | NaN        | NaN        | NaN        |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I'm struggling to get this using unstack/pivot or other Pandas built-ins as I keep running into:

`ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

due to the repeated user IDs.

My solution at the moment uses a loop to index the individual timeseries and concatenates them together so it's not scalable - it's already really slow with just 180k rows:

```
def time_series_stacker(df):

  ts = list()

  for user in df['user_id'].unique():

    values = df.loc[df['user_id']==user].drop('user_id', axis=1).T.values

    instance = pd.DataFrame(
        values[1,:].reshape(1,-1), 
        index=[user],
        columns=values[0,:].astype('datetime64[ns]')
    )

    ts.append(instance)

  return pd.concat(ts, axis=0)
```

Can anyone help out with reshaping this more efficiently please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect time to try out `pivot_table`

```
    user_id  order_date    values
0  11039591  2017-01-01  3277.466
1  11039591  2017-01-02   587.553
2  13629086  2017-01-03   501.882
3  13629086  2017-01-02  1352.546
4   6084613  2017-01-01   441.151

df.pivot_table(index='user_id',columns='order_date',values='values')
```

Output

```
order_date  2017-01-01  2017-01-02  2017-01-03
user_id
6084613        441.151         NaN         NaN
11039591      3277.466     587.553         NaN
13629086           NaN    1352.546     501.882
```

Comment: Haha I realise I've just described the functionality of a pivot table exactly in my question - I guess I didn't consider it because I automatically associate them with aggregating, but if I've only got one observation per day then the aggfunc doesn't matter. Perfect answer, thanks!